# vavr Validation stream of validators

Tags: java, validation, vavr

I have a code like this:

```
  return validators
            .stream()
            .flatMap(v -> v.validate(scoreRequest).stream())
            .collect(toList());
```

Each validator returns a `List<String>` of errors, if the list is empty it means that the request is valid.

Now I want to introduce vavr.Validator. The new return type of each validator.validate now is `Validation<List<String>,ScoreRequest>`

How can I combine the output of each validators using streams like before?

Comment: I think you have to clarify your requirements. How could we tell you what *you* intend to do with that changed signature?! You changed the signature of that method to return a validation object. Now *you* have to determine how you want to reasonably process that?!

Comment: I just want to combine all the validations performed by each validator. The output of the combine should be: `Validation<List<String>,ScoreRequest>`

Comment: You say that **each** validate() method returns a Validation object. How do you expect to merge those? How do you get from a list of ScoreRequest to a single one?!

Comment: I thought that the Valivation.combine would have done exactly this. Combine the `List<String>` of errors or return the scoreRequest if the request is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sequence](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Validation.html#sequence-java.lang.Iterable-) to do exactly that.

So if your `validators` is a `List<Validation<List<String>, ScoreRequest>>`, applying this function to it will return a `Validation<Seq<String>, Seq<ScoreRequest>>`, which looks exactly like what you want. I let you figure out the plumbing of converting back the `Seq`s to whatever structure you want.